# How do I evaluate the expectation value $\left \langle \hat{p}^{2} \right \rangle$ for a quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

The probability function of a quantum SHO is:

$$P(x)=Ae^{-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}}$$

where $A$ is a factor required for normalisation.

The operator is:

$$\hat{p}^{2}=(-i\hbar\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x})^{2}=-\hbar^{2}\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}}{\textrm{d}x^{2}}$$

Therefore the expectation value is:

$$\left \langle \hat{p}^{2} \right \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-\hbar^{2}\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}}{\textrm{d}x^{2}}\times A^{2}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}})\textrm{d}x$$

However I had difficulty evaluating this integral, and when I inserted it into WolframAlpha out of laziness I obtained an answer of 0, which should be false since otherwise it would not agree with the uncertainty principle inequality. Where have I gone wrong in the above process?

WolframAlpha calculations (I removed the constants for simplicity):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+order+derivative+of+e%5E(-x%5E2%2Fsigma%5E2)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(e%5E(-x%5E2%2Fsigma%5E2)(4x%5E2-2sigma%5E2))%2Fsigma%5E4+from+-infinity+to+infinity

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics.SE. Please note that homework-like questions are off-topic here unless you ask a specific conceptual question about where you're stuck. Evaluating an integral is specific, but it is not conceptual. Furthermore, "where did I go wrong?" is a [check-my-work type of question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) which is also considered off-topic.

Comment: @count_to_10 That does not sound right... ;-P

Comment: @count_to_10 he asked about the expectation of the kinetic energy, not of the whole energy ;-)

Comment: Decompose the state as sum over the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator and use $p = (a^*-a)$, where $a, a^*$ are creation and annihilation operators. Calculate the expectation value simbolically and most of the contributions will vanish: you'll be left over with one-two simple terms to sum over back.

Comment: @yuggib the penny has  finally dropped regarding my mistake , I am way  out of practice, thanks for your help, I was going to recommend a page with operator methods, which now I'm happy I didn't . Thanks again

Comment: @count_to_10 No problem! ;-)

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry! I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the differential on the wrong expression: It goes on the right wavefunction not on the entire propability distribution. You should get something like:

\begin{align} \langle\hat p^2\rangle & =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\hbar^2\psi(x)\\\\ & =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar \pi})^{1/2}[-(m\omega x)^2+\hbar m\omega]\exp(-\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}x^2)dx \\\\ & = \frac1 2\hbar m \omega. \end{align}

If you apply the derivative to $\psi(x)^*\psi(x)$ instead of $\psi(x)$ you get down the wrong terms.

Comment: If the normalisation factor is squared because the wavefunction is multiplied by itself, why is it still rooted in the second line?

Comment: The normalisation factor in the wave function is $(\frac{m\omega}{\pi\hbar})^{1/4}$ so squared it is to the power of $\frac 1 2$.